# Spark Async interface for Fold, Reduce, Aggregate?

Tags: asynchronous, apache-spark, future

In the official Spark RDD API:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/AsyncRDDActions.html

count, collect, foreach, and take all have async variants that return a Future.

Why do fold, reduce, and aggregate not have this async/future interface? That seems pretty important.

Comment: And saveAsObjectFile

Comment: Agreed. This is a disturbing inconsistency in the Spark API. If anything, it would make more sense to provide an asynchronous option for `fold` since it's more general and you could use it to create an asynchronous `reduce` or `count`.

Answer (score 0):

## !!! Edited

@Jan Van den bosch is right (see comments below). This question is not about transformations at all. In case someone else was fooled, I've left my misguided answer below.

## !!! Original Answer (incorrect)

**TL;DR:** The difference is between spark "actions" vs. "transformations": https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations

---

Notice, that all the things you listed with an asynchronous option are spark **"actions"**, which means they will start processing the data right away and attempt to return synchronously. It may take a long time if there's a lot of data, so it's nice to have an asynchronous option.

Meanwhile, the operations you listed without an asynchronous option are spark **"transformations"** which are lazily evaluated, which means it instantly creates a plan to do the work, but it won't actually process any data until you apply an "action" later to return results.

Meanwhile, do you have **specific code** or a problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: It's not about actions vs transformations, it's about getting the results synchronously (`.collect()`) vs asynchronously (`.collectAsync()`).

Comment: @Jan Van den bosh, actually, because they are transformations, they aren't running things at all (sync or async). You would have to do an action to get the result of the transformation anyway. Are you saying you can do `rdd.fold(...).collect`, but for some reason `rdd.fold(...).collectAsync` doesn't work? That would be very surprising to me, since the `fold` and the `collect(Aysnc)` should independent.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. This question isn't about transformations at all. It's about having the methods `collect` + `collectAsync`, and `count` + `countAsync`, but not a `reduceAsync`, or a `foldAsync`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, @Jan Van den bosch. I rarely use spark's fold and reduce methods, so I was was actually thinking about when I use scala's fold or reduce within a spark `map` or grouping of some sort.